# Getting error while signing xml document with X509Certificate(SalesForce certificate) in C# for Single Sign-On SAML post

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, salesforce, single-sign-on, saml

I am trying to `Single Sign-On` with `SAML POST` to SalesForce. I have created SalesForce sandbox account, downloaded `Certificate` from `Certificate and Key Management`. I am using that `Certificate`in my C# code but it gives error `Signing key is not loaded.` at following code

```
 XmlElement signature = SigningHelper.SignDoc(xmlDocument, certificate, "ID", refValue);
```

While my debugging I found when it creates certificate instance as following

```
certificate = new X509Certificate2("d:/certificate.crt", "testpassword", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
```

instance is created but property `certificate.PrivateKey` remains null due to may be it is giving error `Signing key is not loaded.`

Any idea how to create signature with certificate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of R&D I got to know c# code

```
XmlElement signature = SigningHelper.SignDoc(xmlDocument, certificate, "ID", refValue);
```

requires private key file of certification whereas I was trying with public key file.